# UnsatisfiedLinkError building native library for Java SE

Tags: java, c++, gradle

I built an android library that is mostly just a wrapper for a native(C++) library that does some crypto functions. The library uses CMake for the native code build and calls the native methods via the JNI bridge. I want to make this same library work for Java SE(non android Java), but I am stuck and cannot make the CMake build the native code.
This is what the CMakeLists looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)


project(utilities-whitebox)

set(WHITEBOXDIR utilities-whitebox/whitebox)

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
        utilities_whitebox

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

#        SwigWbc_wrap.cpp
        src/main/cpp/SwigWbc_wrap.cpp
        ${WHITEBOXDIR}/src/utilities_whitebox.cpp
        ${WHITEBOXDIR}/src/WhiteBoxInterpreter.cpp
        ${WHITEBOXDIR}/src/WhiteBoxUtils.cpp
)

include_directories(
        ${WHITEBOXDIR}/include
        ${WHITEBOXDIR}/src
)
```

The directories and files listed in the CMakelists all exist and are in the appropriate path. This is the error I get when I go to load the the native code using the `System.loadLibrary("utilities_whitebox")` call.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no utilities_whitebox in java.library.path: [/Users/soere/Library/Java/Extensions, /Library/Java/Extensions, /Network/Library/Java/Extensions, /System/Library/Java/Extensions, /usr/lib/java, .]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
```

I believe the my app is simply not running the cmake command which needs to be executed successfully before the native code can be used in the Java SE classes. I believe I may have to add a gradle task that does the native build first using cmake before building the java app. Is this correct? How do I go about this?

Comment: It looks like `utilities_whitebox` is using a library called `utilities_crypto` which has not been included.

Comment: @RichardCritten apologies, I modified the stacktrace. I have updated to show the right thing. It is looking for the `utilities_whitebox`.

Comment: When you manually invoke cmake, do you end up with a working library? If that works you can indeed instruct gradle to run cmake for you.